# HTTP 500 error when trying to edit magento theme setting

Tags: magento2, theme, custom-theme

I just installed Magento 2.3 with sample data on an Ubuntu 18 VM.

I'm playing around with creating themes based on tutorials I found online. I created a sample theme, uploaded it, logged into admin, and then switched to it with no issues.

Now, I'm having an issue trying to switch to an alternative theme. For some reason, I can't seem to change themes anymore; even though I could before.

Here are the steps I go through:

> 1. Log in to the admin panel
> 2. Go to Menu -> Content -> Configuration
> 3. Click 'Edit' under 'Action' column

What I now get is a page that looks like this:

[image: HTTP Error 500]

I don't recall doing anything noteworthy after I first switched themes from the default to the new one I created.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

The URL reporting the 500 error is the following:

> `https://<my-magento-install-url>/admin/theme/design_config/edit/scope/stores/scope_id/1/key/<some-long-number>/`

Comment: the error in the image seems to be a wordpress error

Comment: I've updated the image to avoid confusion. The one I posted was meant to show the kind of page, not the actual page itself.

Comment: are you in a developer mode?

Comment: how about in error log, what did you get in error logs?